# WordPress site hacked with conditional script

Tags: php, wordpress

Yesterday i got a bug in my wordpress site, where hacker injected a script which can be seen by googlebot only.

That script is not read or identified on normal browsers.
This is not causing issues site availability or performance but on google search it gives advertisements instead of my site content. which is not good.

while searching on google i got this
https://aw-snap.info/articles/spam-hack-wordpress.php

I tried almost all the options given there.

Can anybody help me to identify the spam?

Thanks

Kiran Peshkar

Comment: I found Word fence -WordPress plugin very effective to identify the affected files. I scanned my code base using that superb plugin and resolved the issue. now all my google results are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google offers a "view as Google" option in webmaster tools.  This will help you to see what they see.

I tend to do two things if recovering one of my sites is not obvious what has caused the problem.

1. Upload a fresh copy of WordPress to my server.  This will overwrite all the core files so if any have been hacked the malicious code will be overwritten.
2. It is likely that a malicious script is hidden somewhere so if it is a simple site I will delete everything and reinstall and re upload plugins.  Of course anything in wp-content will need to be saved and restored.  But note, a malicious script could be hidden in here.
3. It might just be easier to do a full restore at this point.  Find a recent backup, upload the files and check with Google's tool to see if the malicious code is still active.  It is always worth contacting your webhost for help, depending on how good they are they might even sort this out for you.

Remember, any attempt to restore or overwrite files could potentially impact your site or result in data loss so make sure you backup everything you need.  Although it is unlikely the malicious code is in the WordPress database you should definitely back this up too.

Unfortunately there is no easy way to remove these types of hack, you never quite know what malicious code has been used.  You should consider changing all passwords and reviewing your security so that the hacker doesn't do the same thing again as soon as you get the site up!  Make sure all apps on the server are up to date.

Even the most secure WordPress sites get hit from time to time, this is why security is important and why daily backups are essential.